# LogIn form with user and admin using VB.net and Mysql

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the privilege if it's admin or encoder but with this code I can't get any value... this is my code  please help me

```
 Private Sub OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    cn = New MySqlConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; database=dp_inventory;"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        cn.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "Select  from dp_inventory.user_account where employeeID='" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and password='" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "' "
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While reader.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While
        Dim users As String
        users = "select privilege from user_account where employeeID='" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "'"
        If count = 1 Then
            If users = "admin" Then
                frmAdminMain.Show()
            ElseIf users = "encoder" Then
                MainForm.Show()
            End If
        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            frmAdminMain.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("tryy again")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Try again")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: First fix the SQL Injection vulnerabilities, then don't store passwords as plaintext (they needed to be well salted hashes).

Comment: That made me lost even more. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few errors in this code you wrote. Your first issue is you are simply trying to count without actually using a Sql counter.

Take a look at a code snippet from one of my applications here for a general idea

```
SelectStr = "SELECT MagPieces_Number,MagOperators_Number,MagFactor_Number,MagTotal_Number" & _
            " FROM Parts_Mag WHERE Quote_Number_Id = @QuoteId and Quote_Rev_Id = @RevId and Part_Number_Id = @PartID and Part_Numeral_Id = @PartNumeral and SiteLocation = @Site"
        SqlDataCmd = New SqlCommand(SelectStr, SqlConn)
        SqlDataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuoteId", QuoteId)
        SqlDataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RevId", RevId)
        SqlDataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartId", PartNumber)
        SqlDataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumeral", PartNumeral)
        SqlDataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site", SiteLocation)

        SqlReader = SqlDataCmd.ExecuteReader

        While SqlReader.Read
            MagPieces = SqlReader("MagPieces_Number").ToString
            MagOperators = SqlReader("MagOperators_Number").ToString
            MagFactor = SqlReader("MagFactor_Number").ToString
            MagTotal = SqlReader("MagTotal_Number").ToString
        End While

        MagParticle.txtPiecesPerHour.Text = MagPieces
        MagParticle.txtOperators.Text = MagOperators
        MagParticle.txtMatFactor.Text = MagFactor
        MagParticle.labMagTotal.Text = MagTotal

    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMessage(ex.message)
        SqlReader.Close()
    End Try
    SqlReader.Close()
```

If you are simply looking for if your select statement has "Admin" or "Encoder" at the end, it would simply be something like this:

```
        Dim empId as String = UsernameTextbox.Text
        Dim SelectStr as String = "Select privilege from dp_inventory.user_account where employeeID=@empId
        SqlDataCmd = New SqlCommand(SelectStr, SqlConn)
        SqlDataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empId", empId)
```

Then read it with a reader. Once you have the general idea you should be able to take it from there! Im not quite sure why you need the count to begin with so you may want to just negate that portion out and simply read from your table based on the ID